# How to resolve the "Plaid API: Unable to fetch link_token" error

Tags: python, node.js, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, plaid

I am attempting to run the plaid api using python on windows 11 and I keep getting an error when trying to load the quickstart. I am using git bash as my shell, and my .env file appears to be correct, but I have not been successful getting it running.

My .env looks like the below file.

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PLAID_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PLAID_ENV=sandbox
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:3000/'
```

The python server side outputs the following.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2022 00:33:14] "POST /api/info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2022 00:33:15] "POST /api/create_link_token HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The frontend side outputs a series of warnings of the form below.

```
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
```

Lastly, the frontend page displays the following error.

[Plaid Frontend Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96aoA.png)

I am new to flask and the plaid api, so I am not sure how to remedy this issue. I originally got the frontened working correctly but unfortunately broke it along the way. I am running the non-docker version of the quickstart and am using npm 6.14.15 and node 14.18.3. I ran into errors using the most recent release (18.2.0) and reverted following another stackoverflow thread. I also used the correct git clone command with simulinks set to true, so I do not think that is the issue.

Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

I tried logging the create_link_token() method but it runs into an error and outputs the exception:

```
{
"display_message": null,
"documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-input-errors",
"error_code": "INVALID_API_KEYS",
"error_message": "invalid client_id or secret provided",
"error_type": "INVALID_INPUT",
"request_id": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
"suggested_action": null
}
```

When it reaches the call:

```
response = client.link_token_create(request)
```

I pulled my API keys directly from plaid, but I am double checking now.

Comment: You mentioned that you originally had it working and then it broke -- can you just reset your local state to origin/master and then try setting it up again? If that doesn't work, can you log the response to the `create_link_token` call and provide it here?

Comment: Hey Alex, please see the revision. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

It appears I set the .env file up for a development build instead of the sandbox. Once I corrected the api key and redirect, the API now works!